# deploy gunicorn and uvicorn using systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, python

Can you please advise why the `uvicorn` worker class doesn't load on `gunicorn` when using `systemd` ?

When I initiate `gunicorn` like:

`/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5045 --forwarded-allow-ips="x.x.x.x" --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --pid /home/xxx/ip-spotlight/run/pid/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.pid --error-logfile /var/log/ip-spotlight/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.error.log --access-logfile /var/log/ip-spotlight/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.access.log --capture-output glass:app`

it works properly:

```
[2019-12-10 22:08:55 +0100] [1288] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2019-12-10 22:08:55 +0100] [1288] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5045 (1288)
[2019-12-10 22:08:55 +0100] [1288] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2019-12-10 22:08:55 +0100] [1293] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1293
[2019-12-10 22:08:56 +0100] [1293] [INFO] Started server process [1293]
[2019-12-10 22:08:56 +0100] [1293] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2019-12-10 22:08:56 +0100] [1293] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

But, when using `systemd` to run it as a service, which is configured like:

```
[Unit]
Description=webapp-glass
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User={{ username }}
WorkingDirectory={{ dir.app }}/ip-spotlight/code/web/glass
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/webapp-glass
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn  $OPTIONS  glass:app
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where `/etc/sysconfig/webapp-glass` is:

```
OPTIONS="--bind 127.0.0.1:5045 --forwarded-allow-ips="x.x.x.x" --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWor
ker --pid /home/xxx/ip-spotlight/run/pid/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.pid --error-logfile /var/log/ip-spotlight/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.error.log --acc
ess-logfile /var/log/ip-spotlight/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.access.log --capture-output"
```

The logs say:

```
Dec 10 22:16:54 nl-ams02c-ispbgp01.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Started webapp-glass.
Dec 10 22:16:54 nl-ams02c-ispbgp01.xxx.xxx gunicorn[1794]: [2019-12-10 22:16:54 +0100] [1794] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Dec 10 22:16:54 nl-ams02c-ispbgp01.xxx.xxx gunicorn[1794]: [2019-12-10 22:16:54 +0100] [1794] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5045 (1794)
Dec 10 22:16:54 nl-ams02c-ispbgp01.xxx.xxx gunicorn[1794]: [2019-12-10 22:16:54 +0100] [1794] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Dec 10 22:16:54 nl-ams02c-ispbgp01.xxx.xxx gunicorn[1794]: [2019-12-10 22:16:54 +0100] [1798] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1798
```

It says that `Using worker: sync` (instead of `Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`) which is wrong because the app is based on ASGI, hence it crashes because it necessitates `uvicorn`.

Would you be so kind and suggest why the correct worker class is not loaded ?

Comment: Wild guess: `--forwarded-allow-ips="x.x.x.x"` shouldn't have quotes

Comment: woah! thank you! you are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systemd environment files and declarations don't use shell syntax. It just supports some limited quoting and expansion. So where `"--bind 127.0.0.1:5045 --forwarded-allow-ips="x.x.x.x" --..."` after quote removal is simply `--bind 127.0.0.1:5045 --forwarded-allow-ips=x.x.x.x --...` in a shell (assuming default IFS, and no filename expansion), it's not the same thing in a systemd `EnvironmentFile`.

Note also that what you intended to do (add quotes inside a quoted string) was unnecessary, and anyway didn't work the way you might have thought it did. What a shell will see is the quoted string `--bind 127.0.0.1:5045 --forwarded-allow-ips=` followed by the unquoted string `x.x.x.x` followed by the quoted string `--workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --pid...`, and it will simply concatenate them. However, filename expansion doesn't take place in variable assignment, so you'd only have seen a problem if there was a space or tab in `x.x.x.x` (not a worry, since it's an IP). The line should have been just:

```
OPTIONS="--bind 127.0.0.1:5045 --forwarded-allow-ips=x.x.x.x --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --pid /home/xxx/ip-spotlight/run/pid/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.pid --error-logfile /var/log/ip-spotlight/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.error.log --access-logfile /var/log/ip-spotlight/ip-spotlight.webapp.glass.access.log --capture-output"
```

And that would have worked for both shell and systemd.